# How to create a plugin that notifies for updates?

Tags: plugins, updates, private

At this point when I activate a plugin and an update is available it updates the plugin. I like to create a plugin myself that I want to use private, I have several WordPress blogs and if I made an update to the plugin I like those several WordPress blogs to state that there is an update available. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: If you don't want to roll your own solution, you can use kernl.us for hosted plugin updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a plugin for that: [Automatic Updates For Private And Commercial Plugins](http://w-shadow.com/blog/2010/09/02/automatic-updates-for-any-plugin/).

To prevent upgrade checks against the WordPress.org data base in your plugin use the [function Mark Jaquith has written](http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/14/excluding-your-plugin-or-theme-from-update-checks/).

Comment: Note that update check requests were changed to use JSON and Jaquith's functions no longer work as-is on current WP version.